# git gui create custom shortcut for branch name

Tags: git, branch

I just realized that I start ALL my git commit messages with the name of the branch I'm currently working with. Which in turn is the issue number I'm working on. It would be extremely convenient for me to have a keyboard shortcut similar to the sign-off shortcut that just printed the current branch's name.

I looked into `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui.tcl` (yes, I'm on Windows :-( ) but I'm totally lost. I did a quick `grep` on this folder, but I couldn't find where the `do_signoff` command is defined (so I could try to copy it).

So my question is: how to implement a custom keyboard shortcut that puts the current branch name in the commit message?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this a practice? Branches are temporary. They can be renamed or moved.

Comment: We work with Jira, so for *anything* we do, we create an issue for that. It only makes sense that I work on a branch X-123 that is solving bug # X-123. Besides, if the issue number is in the commit message, Jira (and Bugzilla and a bunch of other tools) will use a push hook on the server to relate commits with issues.

Comment: I also work with jira, as long as a branch is named with the issue number, it can track it.

Comment: Good. I still would like that shortcut though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.

Clone the git-gui repo, like so:

```
git clone git://repo.or.cz/git-gui.git
```

Add the following to `git-gui\lib\commit.tcl`

```
proc do_branch_name {} {
    global ui_comm
    global current_branch
    if {$current_branch eq {}} return

    set sob "$current_branch"
    set last [$ui_comm get {end -1c linestart} {end -1c}]
    if {$last ne $sob} {
        $ui_comm edit separator
        if {$last ne {}
            && ![regexp {^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z-]+: *} $last]} {
            $ui_comm insert end "\n"
        }
        $ui_comm insert end "$sob:"
        $ui_comm edit separator
        $ui_comm see end
    }
}
```

To bind CTRL+b as the keyboard shortcut, add the following to `Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui.tcl`:

```
bind .   <$M1B-Key-b> do_branch_name
```

You still need to regenerate the `tclIndex` do tcl actually finds your new function. In the git-gui repo folder, do

```
make lib/tclIndex
```

This should create the `git-gui\lib\tclIndex` file.

Replace `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-gui\lib\commit.tcl` with `git-gui\lib\commit.tcl`.

Replace `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-gui\lib\tclIndex` with `git-gui\lib\tclIndex`

Now, if you press CTRL+b, it will place the current branch's name in the commit message window.

Cheers!